# Sed replacement on bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following string

```
<dataSource jndiName="worklightconsole/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
```

and I want to replace the word 'worklightconsole' with 'app' so that the output looks like below

```
<dataSource jndiName="app/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
```

I tried the following (and few other options) using 'sed' but could not make it work

```
sed -e 's/\<dataSource\ jndiName=\".*\//\dataSource\ jndiName=\"app\//g'
```

and I got the output as

```
<dataSource jndiName="app/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
```

Instead of replacing the word 'worklightconsole' it replaced 'worklightconsole/jdbc' with 'app'

What am I doing wrong and also what is meant by '.*' in sed?

Comment: I think you can use `s/jndiName=\"[^\"\/]+/jndiName=\"app/g` ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's|(jndiName=")[^/]*(/jdbc/WorklightDS")|\1app\2|' file
```

to replace "in place":

```
sed -E -i 's|(jndiName=")[^/]*(/jdbc/WorklightDS")|\1app\2|' file
```

---

`.`: matches any character one time

`.*`: matches any character zero or more times

Comment: It worked like a charm.  However, can you explain me how that pattern works especially I am eager to know what is '\1app\2'?

Comment: `\1` refers to the expression in first pair of round brackets `jndiName="` and `\2` refers to the expression in second pair of round brackets `/jdbc/WorklightDS"`. With `\1app\2` the result is `jndiName="app/jdbc/WorklightDS"`

Comment: Great explanation, Thank you